# Will assigning a static object to another (non-static) variable make a copy of that object?

Tags: c#, monogame, static-variables

I have a static class that holds static textures for use throughout the game.

```
public static class AssetManager
{

    public static Texture2D someTexture;
    ....
}
```

My question is, if I were to assign that static texture to a variable in another class, like this:

```
Texture2D classTexture = AssetManager.someTexture;
```

would I be creating a copy of that texture? I'm really not thinking I would be and reading about it, I don't think thats how a static variable should work. I tried it out and checked the hashCode of each and they seemed to be the same. But I'm also not sure if thats the correct way to be checking and I don't want to run into a problem later on where I'm creating a bunch of new textures that I don't need.

Comment: is `Texture2D` a value type?

Comment: The only way I know to check is (texture is ValueType). Xamarin said that the object would never be a value type. I didn't think it would be because its an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# never makes implicit copies of objects.

It kind of sounds like your caution may be coming from a C++ background, in which case you can think of all objects in C# as being a pointer.

Comment: I got a very previous-C++-experience vibe from the nature of the question. If you don't have C++ experience, then the answer is simply an unqualified "Nope". :)